# how to add a bitmapfont to my dialog in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can draw a paragraph using bitmapfont in my dialog

```
public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("", skin) {};
    stage.addActor(dialog);
}
```

Comment: I guess you could add a label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dialog` has a public method `text` that let you add a label to the dialog. Using your `BitmapFont` you can create a [LabelStyle](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.LabelStyle.html) object then [Label](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html) and provide it as argument

```
LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle();
labelStyle.font = yourBitmapFont;    

Label label = new Label("Hello world!", labelStyle);
dialog.text(label);
// You can also use: dialog.text("Hello world!", labelStyle)
```